# Clear Device Cache after logout - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my application, when I logout, I’m clearing the localStorage using `localStorage.clear();`

But after login, if I login with some other means, after sometimes my previous ID details only visible. But after logout, when I clean device RAM and open the app means it shows correct data.

I’m assuming that it is due to cache. How to clear the view cache on logout or on leaving a screen?

Comment: The tags are wrong... is this related to Ionic 2/3 or Ionic v1?